# 2 parts of number comparsion

Tags: regex, grep

How can I compare two parts of number and matched only equal of them?

```
$> tail foo | grep -E "([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})"
999690
999700
999706
999760
999790
999851
999859
999895
999916
999949
```

And what ???? sould be for smth like that?

```
$> grep -E ???? foo | tail
111111
222222
345345
997997
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already grouped the first part; now reference it using `\1`.

```
grep -E "([0-9]{3})\1" foo
```

`\n` must be identical to the n:th paren.